# Short circuit local reads in Cloudera Search

Tags: search, solr, hdfs, cloudera

I would like to know if short circuit local reads works with Cloudera Search? I think this can have significant performance improvement but I could not find any documentation on this feature.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cloudera:

> Short circuit reads have not been enabled nor tested for Solr, as there is not a major performance improvement to be gained by using SCLR. Solr would only see performance improvement on startups, while the caches are warmed. If you would like to remove the WARN message from your logs, you could add the following to the Solr Service Configuration-> Default Group -> Advanced -> Java Configuration Options for Solr Server:

```
-Djava.library.path=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/lib/native
```

> This will remove the WARN messages from your logs.